# Battle of the brains; cultural mathematics 

Tags: soft-question, mathematics-education, big-list

Firstly, I apologize if my question is long.

Three years ago, I watched a video with the name *Battle of the Brains.* It was a wonderful video about challenging some famous peoples to solve some special problems. I learned many new things from this video. Unfortunately, I could not find any similar video, but I interested in the abilities of people to attack a problem.

So, I studied many references about the system of educations in different countries. I found many parameters as like as; teacher education and qualifications, academic standards, teacher effectiveness, lesson plans and modules, teacher characteristics, instructional materials, program effectiveness, program evaluation,  culture,  history, class activities, educational games, number systems, cognitive ability, foreign influence, and fundamental concepts, are so important in learning mathematics.

Recently, I found the book *African Mathematics: From Bones to Computers by  Mamokgethi Setati, Abdul Karim Bangura* that is very interesting. I think there are some good references as like as this book. My requests are:

1. Would you please introduce me video files as like as *Battle of the Brains*?
2. Would you please introduce textbooks or sites that are about cultural mathematics as like as the book above?

I think there are some references about the research of American mathematicians in Chinese cultural mathematics. I will appreciate, if someone reference these documents.

Comment: In reading on this subject, one should be careful.  It sometimes attracts cranks with amazing claims and no valid evidence.

Answer (score 2):

George Gheverghese Joseph, [The Crest of the Peacock](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/9308.html): Non-European Roots of Mathematics (Third Edition), Princeton University Press.

Comment: I looked the title of chapters of this book. I think It is good references for second question. Thanks dear Myerson

Answer (score 2):

Claudia Zaslavsky, [Africa Counts](http://www.ethnomath.org/resources/zaslavsky1999.pdf): Number and Pattern in African Cultures, Third Edition.

Comment: Hmm, I couldn't access the link. Something wrong? No more available? Perhaps there is another source elsewhere?

Comment: @Gottfried, don't know what to tell you - it works for me, although it only gives the first 45 pages of the book. 

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. I get 404.

Comment: Doesn't work for me any more, either. If you register with JSTOR, you can get it at http://www.jstor.org/stable/40248107?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents Or, you can buy it at Amazon.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ethnomath.org/